# How can I create a specific JSON string?

Tags: php, json

I want to create this JSON string with PHP:

```
[{name:'20140722.1304',data:[[0, 0.224],[0, 0.228]] }, {name:'20140729.1149',data:[[1, 0.224],[1,0.228]] }]
```

My current attempt:

```
$jsonArray = array(
    'name' => '20140722.1304'
   ,'data' => array('0' => '0.024', '1'=> '0.028')
);

$jsonValue = json_encode($jsonArray);
echo $jsonValue;
```

But this code's output looks like:

```
{"name":"20140722.1304","data":["0.024","0.028"]}
```

Where did I went wrong? What do I have to change in my code to get to my expected output?

Comment: The "JSON" object you're trying to generate isn't JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal. It's unclear what you think the problem is. Is it that you only have one element, where your expected output has two? Or is it that your numbers are coming out as strings? You need to ask a specific question here.

Comment: but i need to pass that format to HighCharts as highcharts only supports that format. is there any way to generate that kinds of formant using php?

Comment: Your "php array" has only one entry, your desired output has 2. You have to provide an array of entries to `json_encode`.

Comment: @KyungmoKim *What* format? The format you've output is exactly what you've inputted. If you want to output an array, your *input* to `json_encode` must be an array. Tell us what part of the output you're getting now isn't correct, or we can't help you.

Comment: @meagar Thanks, the array I made would be wrong. somehow I want to get the output as {name:'20140722.1304',data:[[0, 0.224],[0, 0.228]]} this format. is it possible to create with php array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got you to tell us what you want in the comments; please be up-front with this in the future. The expected output you gave differed from your actual output in so many ways that it was impossible to tell what you actually thought the problem was, but:

> I want to get the output as {name:'20140722.1304',data:[[0, 0.224],[0, 0.228]]}

At this point, the only difference I can see is that  your `data` is a nested array in your expected output, but not your *actual* output.

That has nothing to do with JSON. You're just not building your input array correctly.

Try json-encoding this:

```
$jsonArray = array(
    'name' => '20140722.1304'
   ,'data' => array(array(0, 0.024), array(0, 0.028))
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what I exactly want :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
$jsonArray[] = array(
        'name' => '20140722.1304'
       ,'data' => array('0' => '0.024', '1'=> '0.028')
  );
  }
  //$jsonValue = json_encode($jsonArray);
  $jsonValue = json_encode($jsonArray,true);
  echo$jsonValue;
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
    $jsonArray = array(
        'name' => '20140722.1304'
       ,'data' => array('0' => '0.024', '1'=> '0.028')
  );
  $out = array_values($jsonArray);

  echo json_encode($out);
```

output:

```
["20140722.1304",["0.024","0.028"]]
```

EDit:

```
 $array = array(
  2 => array("name" => '20140722.1304'),
  4 => array("'data" => array('0' => '0.024', '1'=> '0.028')));
 $out = array_values($array);
 echo json_encode($out);
```

output:

```
[{"name":"20140722.1304"},{"'data":["0.024","0.028"]}]
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to generate {name:'20140722.1304',data:[[0, 0.224],[0, 0.228]] } ??

Comment: yes, it is similar, but the output doesnt have the 0 in front of values.