# Ajax 404 error not found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm facing problem with ajax call.

Here is my limk where i'm using ajax call http://www.cholokhai.com/resturant/test-demo/

I have included script in footer file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and code of ajax call is:

```
jQuery("#next_button").click(function(e){
        jQuery(".fetch_data").hide();
        jQuery(".booking_confirm").show();

        var selected_date = jQuery("#selected_date").text();
        var selected_persons = jQuery("#selected_persons").text();
        var selected_discount = jQuery("#discount_time").text();
        var selected_price = jQuery("#discount_price").text();

        var filled_name = jQuery("#selected_name").val();
        var filled_email = jQuery("#selected_email").val();
        var filled_phone = jQuery("#selected_phone").val();

        var postData = 'name='+filled_name+'&email='+filled_email+'&phone='+filled_phone+'&date='+selected_date+'&persons='+selected_persons+'&time='+selected_discount+'&discount='+selected_price;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : "http://www.cholokhai.com/ajax",
            type: "POST",
            data : {v:postData},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(html)
            {
                jQuery(".booking_confirm").show();

            }
        }); 

        return false;
    });
```

When im using variables not string in data like: data{name: filled_name, email: filled_email}
im getting 404 error.

I don't know why its not working.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  Do NOT include jQuery this way.  It will cause all sorts of problems.  Use the proper way.  See my answer here on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321767/wordpress-inline-js-cant-get-working/34322445#34322445

Comment: `404 error` means `url` is wrong...

Comment: 404 means page not found. If http://www.cholokhai.com is the base url of you application, you should just use : url : "/ajax"

Comment: AJAX in WordPress is very specifically engineered.  I strongly recommend you read this article: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/ and / or this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-primer-on-ajax-in-the-wordpress-frontend-understanding-the-process--wp-27052

Comment: you are formatting your data to be sent as if it was part of a url. You should be sending it as a serialized json object.

Comment: @DinoMyte  I did this but it showed me same error.

Comment: I'm facing another issue. Im unable to get data of ajax. Im using $_POST['v'] within variable and echo but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a string fit for a URL as in with Query String parameters while what you need is to pass a json object.

You can either manually create it or you can parse an object.  bottom line that is not a JSON string. Have a look at something like this: [How can I create a specific JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182080/how-can-i-create-a-specific-json-string), it should help

Comment: Im using ajax call for url http://www.cholokhai.com/resturant/test-demo/ where resturant is my custom post type. and test-demo is my post